# How to find number of unique connection using hive/pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have a sample table like below:

```
caller   receiver 
100         200
100         300
400         100
100         200
```

I need to find the number of unique connection for each number. 
For ex: 100 will have connections like 200,300 and 400.

My output should be like:

```
100      3  
200      1  
300      1  
400      1
```

I am trying this by using hive. If this can not be  done by hive then is it ok to do it by pig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
 select q1.caller,count(distinct(q1.receiver)) from 
(select caller , receiver from test_1 group by caller,receiver 
union all 
select receiver as caller,caller as receiver from test_1 group by receiver,caller)q1 group by q1.caller;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is ***a*** way to do what you require (although I'm not entirely convinced it is optimal, but I'll leave it to you to optimize).  You'll need [this jar](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse), its pretty straight forward how to build.

**Query:**

```
add jar ./brickhouse-0.7.1.jar; -- name and path of yours will be different
create temporary function combine_unique as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUniqueUDAF';

select connection
  , size(combine_unique(arr)) c
from (
  select connection, arr
  from (
    select caller as connection
      , collect_set(receiver) arr
    from some_table
    group by caller ) x
  union all
  select connection, arr
  from (
    select receiver as connection
      , collect_set(caller) arr
    from some_table
    group by receiver ) y ) f
group by connection
```

**Output:**

```
connection    c
100           3
200           1
300           1
400           1
```